# React native app is not rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFAik.jpg)

Not really sure what I did wrong because everything looks right with my code, at least if I missed something.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Home from "./screens/home";
import { View } from "react-native";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { AppLoading } from "expo-app-loading";

const getFonts = () =>
  Font.loadAsync({
    "poppins-regular": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
    "poppins-bold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),
  });

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return <Home />;
  } else {
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={getFonts} onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing

```
import { AppLoading } from "expo-app-loading";
```

to this:

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

Comment: Thanks for this! it's no longer giving me the error. However, it's not loading anything on my phone when i run it on expo. It's giving me this error in my terminal though: AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading: Error: AppLoading onError prop is required if startAsync is provided

By any chance would you know what i should be doing here? Is it my async syntax now since the new expo update?

Comment: Basically you need to set onError={//anything here} prop on the <AppLoading component. Take a look at this example: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/

Make sure to accept the answer if it solved the problem for others to see and benefit! Happy coding